# Extract two values from text

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to obtain two values with php regex in this kind of strings:

```
bla bla bla

Measures: 10,4 cm x 9 cm.

bla bla bla
```

Results:

```
1: 10,4 (note: decimal values with comma)
2: 9
```

The pattern `Measures: X cm x Y cm.` is always the same.

I was trying: '@^(?:Measures: )?([^.]+)@' but I can't improve it to obtain the first and second values.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I didn't understand a thing, what do you want to measure? or extract from "bla bla bla" ?

Comment: This is not _do my job_ web-site. ;)

Comment: @PLB Apparently, others are more than obliged to do so.  I wish people felt that way when I ask my more specific and troubleshooted questions.

Comment: PLB is right. Also, I do not see a question. Asking questions this way is rude.

Comment: I know! sorry! I was trying with something similar to that:
'@^(?:measures: )?([^.]+)@'

What is this web for? I think is to help what other people don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$pattern = '~Measures: ([0-9]+,*[0-9]*) cm x ([0-9]+,*[0-9]*)~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $txt, $matches);
$widths = $matches[1];
$heights = $matches[2];
```

Comment: This won't match it since `9 cm` doesn't have a comma. Now why don't you CV it ?

Comment: Commas are apparently optional though, since you can have 9 cm.  The decimal can also be optional, based on that same value.

Comment: Oops overseen it.  thx. have fixed this. @HamZa What means CV?

Comment: Your edited answer now assumes a single digit for the decimal portion.

Comment: @hek2mgl Close Vote ...

Comment: @BLaZuRE I have fixed this.

Comment: @hek2mgl I would use `\d+(?:,\d+)?`

Comment: @HamZa I admit that the pattern can be improved. Like you did, thx ;)

Comment: @HamZa but however, I expect my - more specific version - a bit faster

Comment: @hek2mgl ah I meant to replace this part `[0-9]+,*[0-9]*` with `\d+(?:,\d+)?`

Comment: @Hamza I'm not sure what is faster after thinking more about that. but however, your pattern looks elegant ;)

Comment: Thanks to all! You are a genius! Where can I learn regex to do this kind of searches? :)

Comment: @betus take a look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). You may also check php flavor specific regex by reading the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

Comment: @betus I would advice you to start here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php Especially the section `PCRE regex syntax`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/Measures: (\S+) cm  x (\S+) cm/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $height = $regs[1];
    $width = $regs[2];
}
```